# AVPlayer seek player at NSDate

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation, avplayer, xcode7.3

I have string which text is "00:01:30" in formate of hh:mm:ss.
I want this time as seek time for my video player. Means in sort i want to set 'seekToTime' from string value which is  hh:mm:ss. I convert this in NSDate formate but not able to seeToTime using this. Please suggest.
Thank you.

Comment: What's difficult about writing the code to do this conversion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
self.audioPlayer.timeFormat(self.audioPlayer.getCurrentAudioTime()))


   func getCurrentAudioTime(){ 
   let dur = CMTimeGetSeconds(audioPlayer.currentTime())
    let cmValue = NSTimeInterval(dur)
    let newTime = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(value, 1)
    self.audioPlayer.seekToTime(newTime)
```

}

```
  func timeFormat(value:Double) -> NSString
   {
    let someFloat = Float(value)
    let floatvalue = lroundf(someFloat)
    let floorvalue = Double(floatvalue)

    let minutes = floor(floorvalue / 60)
    let seconds = floorvalue - (minutes * 60)

    let roundsec = Float(seconds)
    let roundmin = Float(minutes)

    let roundedSeconds = lroundf(roundsec)
    let roundedMinutes = lroundf(roundmin)

    var time : NSString!
    time = NSString.init(format:"%d:%02d", roundedMinutes,roundedSeconds)
    return time;
   }
```

Comment: Is it for objective c?

Comment: No,its swift language

Comment: i was asking about objective C. But thanks for suggestion i got the solution.

Answer (score 1):

if you convert the string to CMTime format then assign the seek time, and the code is given below,

```
let fileURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: timeString)!
let asset = AVURLAsset(URL: fileURL, options: nil)
let audioDuration = asset.duration
let newTime:CMTime = CMTimeGetSeconds(audioDuration)
playerVal.seekToTime(newTime)
```

hope its helpful

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the string to CMTime using the code below,

```
func seekTime(timeString:String) -> CMTime? {
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter.init()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss"
    if let startDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString("00:00:00") {
        if let neededDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(timeString) {
            let interval = neededDate.timeIntervalSinceDate(startDate)
            return CMTime.init(value: CMTimeValue(interval), timescale: 1)
        }
    }
    return nil;
}
```